# Button is truncated on the form depending on the screen width

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, user-experience, dock

I have created a winform application and I have the following form:

[image]

The Analyse button is truncated, depending on the screen with.

The DataGridView (under Step 1 section) is fine independently to the screen width. The DataGridview is positioned on a Panel which is located on a GroupBox. Both of DataGridView and Panel are Docked (Fill). I presume this is why I do not have any issues on different screens width.

How should I position the Analyse button so it won't be truncated independently to the screen width?

Comment: what do you want to happen to your button instead? get moved, get hidden, get shortened,..

Comment: I want the button to be visible and not cutted